# Analytics API to gather data for display in own product

Tags: web-development, api, web-services, analytics

I am developing a web app which has users include a javascript snippet on their site, I want to track analytics related to that widget e.g. how often did I user click a button on that widget.

Now, I could just ping back to my server, dump all that data in a Redis and synchronize that data with my sql database at regular intervals.
However, I am wondering whether there is some service out there where I can simply dump events in different buckets and read from it through their API.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can integrate with Google Analytics.

Many websites already use it,  so they will have an account and your users will have to configure your snippet to use their details.

You can [track specific events](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events) and then [embed dashboards](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1/) within other webpages or use the [custom reporting api](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/). See [GA documentation for developers](https://developers.google.com/analytics/).

If it's relevant for you, consider using [GA integration for independent software vendors](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/integrate/isv/), or [GA Technology Partner Program](https://developers.google.com/analytics/program/)